# Creating a CMAudioClock

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avaudioengine, core-media

I am developing an iOS app that generates audio using the AVAudioEngine and displays the video using an AVPlayer. My current problem is that the audio and video are not in sync.

From what I have read, it seems as though I have to create a clock to synchronize the two. According to Apple's docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmaudioclock), the only initializer available on iOS is:

```swift
func CMAudioClockCreate(allocator: CFAllocator?, 
               clockOut: UnsafeMutablePointer<CMClock?>) -> OSStatus
```

From the docs: "Creates a clock that advances at the same rate as audio output."

^^What I am confused about is how this clock will know about the audio output rate? Since the audio output (in my case, the AVAudioEngine) is not even referenced in this initializer.

For example, I can create a CMAudioClock like this:

```swift
var audioClock : CMClock? = nil
CMAudioClockCreate(allocator: nil, clockOut: &audioClock)
```

But this audioClock variable has no reference to my AVAudioEngine (the device it is supposed to track the rate of), AND there is no reference in the AVAudioEngine / AVAudioPlayerNode classes to a Clock reference -- really stumped here.